# a tongue twister in R

Tags: r

This is the text for
 the famous "sea shells" tongue twister:

```
sea_shells <- c(
"She", "sells", "sea", "shells", "by", "the", "seashore",
"The", "shells", "she", "sells", "are", "surely", "seashells",
"So", "if", "she", "sells", "shells", "on", "the", "seashore",
"I'm", "sure", "she", "sells", "seashore", "shells"
)
```

Use the nchar function to calculate the number of letters in each word. Now loop
over possible word lengths, displaying a message about which words have that
length. For example, at length six, you should state that the words "shells" and
"surely" have six letters.?

-

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer accept it.

Comment: There are so many possibilities… e. g. after `levels(factor(sea_shells)) -> words` do `print(aggregate(list(words=words), list(length=nchar(words)), function(x) return(words[x])))` or `print(tapply(words, nchar(words), function(x) return(x)))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sea_shells <- c( "She", "sells", "sea", "shells", "by", "the", "seashore", "The", "shells", "she", "sells", "are", "surely", "seashells", "So", "if", "she", "sells", "shells", "on", "the", "seashore", "I'm", "sure", "she", "sells", "seashore", "shells")
ncharSea_shells <- nchar(Sea_shells, type = "chars", allowNA = FALSE, keepNA = NA)
Sea_shells <- Sea_shells[nchar(Sea_shells)==6]
```

```
dput(Sea_shells)
c("shells", "shells", "surely", "shells", "shells")
```

Should solve your homework problem.

Including the loop:

```
myvars = list()
for (i in min(nchar(Sea_shells)):max(nchar(Sea_shells))) {
  myvars <- list.append(myvars,Sea_shells[nchar(Sea_shells)==i])
}

Homework <- as.data.table(myvars)
```

You can try to create the column names yourself

Comment: This is only part of the solution. The question explicitly asks to loop over all possible word lengths, which is something that is not included in your answer.

Comment: Added that part just now.