# Writing R loop that can display a message detailing words from vector that match a certain length

Tags: r, loops

I am starting with vector

```
sentence <- c("Learning", "loops", "in", "R", "is", "not", "that", "bad")
```

I need to create a loop that can loop over the range of possible word lengths (so 1:8) and then display the words that match each length.

I am new to coding, would love advice on how to get this solution started.

Comment: One approach could be to use the [`seq_along()`](https://r-lang.com/seq_along-function-in-r/) function to count the number of elements in your vector (e.g. `for (i in seq_along(sentences))` then subset the vector ("sentences") if the number of characters matches, i.e. `sentence[nchar(sentence) == i]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up using the following code and it worked out for me. Probably more basic than what you were suggesting, but as I mentioned I am just learning the basics still. Here is what I did                                        sentence <- c("Learning", "loops", "in", "R", "is", "not", "that", "bad")
 lengths <- nchar(sentence)
 min_length <- min(lengths)
 max_length <- max(lengths) 


 for (lengths in min_length:max_length) {
   for (word in sentence) {
     if (nchar(word) == lengths) {
       message('"',word,'"', " has ", lengths, " letters")
     }
   }
 }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a tongue twister in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198131/a-tongue-twister-in-r)